# How do I make an exact recoverable copy of a hard drive?

Tags: data-recovery

I'm looking to buy a new laptop, which comes with Windows 10 preinstalled.

I'm planning to remove it and install ubuntu right away. But I'm afraid that I might run into any driver issues, so I want to somehow make an exact copy of the whole drive (bit by bit), and in case I do want to return the laptop, I'd be able to recover the drive to the condition I got it from the store with.

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can first try live without installing or dual booting with ubuntu before deleting windows completely.

Or you can follow the steps below to create a system image backup referenced from [this](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-make-full-backup-windows-10) step by step guide.

**Steps for creating backup:**

- Open Control Panel.
- Click on System and Security.
- Click on Backup and Restore (Windows 7).
- On the left pane, click the Create a system image link.
- Under "Where do you want to save the backup?" select the On a hard disk option.
- Using the "On a hard disk" drop-down menu, select the storage to save the backup.
- Click the Start backup button.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.